# Execution of shell script from PHP fails

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I have a shell script that connects to mysql database and exports the data to a csv file. I use .my.cnf file to set the credentials for the database so I don't have to use the -u and -p option for mysql to connect.

The shell script works perfectly when I run from the linux command line. When I try to run the same script from PHP code, it fails with error message saying that user@localhost doesn't has permission to connect to the database.

The shell script is owned by the same user that apache is running under and has all the permissions to the script. What am I missing that is causing the error?

The exact error message being returned to the PHP code is "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysqldbuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Scripts from CLI are running as current logged in user. Scripts via browser call run as www-data or any other username the webserver has.

Comment: Markus' comment above is relevant, I think. I would guess the my.cnf file isn't accessible to the apache user.

Comment: Is the `.my.cnf` in the home directory of the user the script is executed under? If not, try and put it there.

Comment: Yes the .my.cnf is in the home directory of the user running the script. In this case, the script and .my.cnf files are owned by the same user that apache is running under.